# XCTAssert with a generic method in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, xctest

I have two almost exactly identical assertions for a generic method on Swift's `Dictionary` structure, but one succeeds and the other fails. I assume that it's how `XCTAssert` works, but can't understand why. Does anyone have an idea why?

If the method is not generic and, for example, `T` is `String`, then both tests succeed.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func safeElement<T>(key: Key, fallback: T) -> T {
        if let value = self[key] as? T {
            return value
        }
        return fallback
    }
}

class DictionaryTests: XCTestCase {
    let dict = ["foo": "bar"]

    func testSafeElement() {
        // This succeeds
        let bar = dict.safeElement("foo", fallback: "")
        XCTAssertEqual(bar, "bar")

        // This fails
        XCTAssertEqual(dict.safeElement("foo", fallback: ""), "bar")
    }
}
```

**Update**

I was tinkering with it a little bit more, and it turns out that if you pass a type as a parameter, then both cases succeed. But I imagine this type verbosity is not that one would want.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func safeElement<T>(key: Key, fallback: T, type: T.Type) -> T {
        if let value = self[key] as? T {
            return value
        }
        return fallback
    }
}

class DictionaryTests: XCTestCase {
    let dict = ["foo": "bar"]

    func testSafeElement() {
        // This succeeds
        let bar = dict.safeElement("foo", fallback: "", type: String.self)
        XCTAssertEqual(bar, "bar")

        // This also succeeds
        XCTAssertEqual(dict.safeElement("foo", fallback: "", type: String.self), "bar")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a print statement:

```
func safeElement<T>(key: Key, fallback: T) -> T {
    print("calling for \(T.self)")
```

You can see the difference in output between the two tests:

```
calling for String
calling for Optional<String>
```

This is probably because XCTAssertEqual's argument is declared as `@autoclosure expression1: () -> T?`, so the compiler tries to pick a version of `safeElement` that returns an optional, which it can do easily by making `T==String?`. But then your `as? T` does the wrong thing, since the dictionary's Value type is a non-optional `String`.

Sounds like [a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: I added some more detail about why I think it happens.

Comment: I've updated the question, maybe it will give you some more ideas.

Comment: The update is not surprising to me: by passing the type as a parameter, you are forcing the compiler to choose the `safeElement<String>` specialization, and wrap the autoclosure's return value, rather than choosing `safeElement<String?>` in the first place. But it might be good info to include in your bug report :)